# Error in installing H2O ai R package in BigInsights cluster in Bluemix

Tags: r, linux, ibm-cloud, h2o, biginsights

I have a 5 node BigInsights hadoop cluster in Bluemix. I am getting error, when I am trying to install H2O ai R in BigInsights cluster.

install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/3/R")))

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘statmod’, ‘RCurl’, ‘jsonlite’ are not available for package ‘h2o’
* removing ‘/home/opus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/h2o’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpJmcuyB/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("h2o", type = "source", repos = (c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/3/R"))) :
  installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I try to install 'RCurl' package of R in BigInsights cluster, getting the error message as:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 916934 bytes (895 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 895 KB

* installing *source* package ‘bitops’ ...
** package ‘bitops’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c bit-ops.c -o bit-ops.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c cksum.c -o cksum.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -o bitops.so bit-ops.o cksum.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/opus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/bitops/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘bitops’
    finding HTML links ... done
    bitAnd                                  html
    bitFlip                                 html
    bitShiftL                               html
    cksum                                   html
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (bitops)
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/opus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RCurl’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpJmcuyB/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RCurl") :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please help me to resolve the issue and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the answer below was right, please accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are trying to install on Linux.
You need to install the development files for libcurl first.

eg

apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

or

yum install libcurl-devel